# Regular Expression for any decimal

Tags: regex

I am having a hard time figuring out a regular expression that would evalute as follows:

(valid)

- .123456
- 1.
- 1.123456
- 123456.1

(not valid)

- 123
- 0...

I tried the following tool but I am not having much luck. (https://www.regex101.com/)

Thank you!

Comment: Why the down votes? I spent about an hour trying various regular expressions but I was not making much progress. So I asked for help here. What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use positive lookahead assertion based regex like below.

```
^(?=.*\d)\d*\.\d*$
```

OR

```
^(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+\.)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/6)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!\.$)\d*\.\d*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/7